# Slower time series simulation with Numba

Tags: python, performance, numpy, time-series, numba

I would like to use the `@njit` decorator from Numba on this code which, given matrices A,B,C,D produces a sample from the state-space model

```
x_n = A@x_{n-1} + B@v_n
y_n = C@x_n + D@v_n
```

```
@njit
def generate_Y_state_space(N, A, B, C, D):
    """
    Simulate M-dimensional time series given state space model defined by A,B,C,D.
    """
    M = A_sim.shape[0]

    v = np.random.normal(0,1/np.sqrt(2),(M,N)) + 1j*np.random.normal(0,1/np.sqrt(2),(M,N)) # complex gaussian randomly variable
    x = np.zeros((M,N),dtype='c16') # 'c16' is the numba type for complex128
    y = np.zeros((M,N),dtype='c16')

    #initialization
    x[:,0] = v[:,0]
    y[:,0] = C@x[:,0] + D@v[:,0]

    for i in range(1,N):
        x[:,i] = A@x[:,i-1] + B@v[:,i]
        y[:,i] = C@x[:,i] + D@v[:,i]

    return y
```

However, without the njit decorator, I get the following performance (N=1000, M=100)

```
%timeit generate_Y_state_space(N, A, B, C, D)
27.9 ms ± 728 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

while with the njit decorator, the performance has not really improved:

```
%timeit generate_Y_state_space(N, A, B, C, D)
24.1 ms ± 6.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

I wonder if the Numba implementation of the matrix multiplication is in fact not better than the Numpy one... Do you have any idea of how could I improve this code ?

Edit : I think that Numba could be able to provide a nice performance improvement not on the matrix multiplication (as Numpy is already pretty fast as pointed out), but more on the for loop (which is necessary here since the whole point of a time series is to generate a new data point as a transformation of the previous one).

Comment: Did you mean "numba implementation ... is in fact not better than the numpy one"?  That wouldn't surprise me.  Numpy routines are already highly optimized C code, delving into assembler for instruction-set specific optimizations.  Numba is not going to help for individual operations.

Comment: Yes indeed, I edited my mistake ! I understand the numpy is already pretty fast, so numba won't speed up a lot. Meanwhile, what takes a lot of time is the for loop which I thought could be improved by using Numba...

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason why you get a slight decrease in performance with Numba is that you need at least to use **`fastmath=True`** in the `@njit` decorator to be as fast as Numpy which internally use it.

Another reason is that the `@njit` decorator **compile the function at runtime** which is a bit slow (and takes often more than 28 ms). You should be careful not to include this compilation time in the benchmark. You can specify the types in the decorator to that Numba can compile the function before the first call (ahead of time). Here is an example:

```py
@njit('c16[:,::1](int64, c16[:,::1], c16[:,::1], c16[:,::1], c16[:,::1])')
```

Moreover, you do not need to zero-initialize the arrays: **`x` and `y` can be left uninitialized**.

Finally, you can speed up the computation using **parallelism**. This is not straightforward here as there is a temporal dependency on `x[:,i]`. However, `B@v[:,i]` and `D@v[:,i]` can be computed in parallel for example. Thus, you can use the parameter `parallel=True` and `prange` rather than `range`.

Here is an (untested) example:

```py
@njit('c16[:,::1](int64, c16[:,::1], c16[:,::1], c16[:,::1], c16[:,::1])', fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def generate_Y_state_space(N, A, B, C, D):
    """
    Simulate M-dimensional time series given state space model defined by A,B,C,D.
    """
    M = A_sim.shape[0]

    v = np.random.normal(0,1/np.sqrt(2),(M,N)) + 1j*np.random.normal(0,1/np.sqrt(2),(M,N)) # complex gaussian randomly variable
    x = np.empty((M,N),dtype='c16') # 'c16' is the numba type for complex128
    y = np.empty((M,N),dtype='c16')

    #initialization
    x[:,0] = v[:,0]
    y[:,0] = C@x[:,0] + D@v[:,0]

    for i in prange(1,N):
        x[:,i] = B@v[:,i]
        y[:,i] = D@v[:,i]

    for i in range(1,N):
        x[:,i] += A@x[:,i-1]
        y[:,i] += C@x[:,i]

    return y
```

Parallelism will not necessary always make the code faster, but it should worth a try on desktop machine.